# Angular Material - Triggering Table Data Refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a `angular-material` table with the `datasource` coming from a `variable array`

The array can have elements pushed to by the onscreen form. This works fine, and the element is pushed and to ensure it I print out the entire datasource and my the new object is reflected there.

Here is that code:

```
reportFields = [{name: "name_test", filter: "filter_test" }];
 addReportField(){
        this.reportFields.push({
            name: this.fieldToAdd.name,
            filter: this.fieldToAdd.filter
        });
        this.frmField.reset();
        this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
        console.log(this.reportFields);
    }
```

reportFields is the datasource, and when the page load the table loads with that data inside. But when I add one during run time, using the addReportField method, the datasource doesn't reload.

I tried using that ChangeDectectorRef and then detect changes but that didn't work.

Here is the HTML for the table

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="reportFields" style="background: inherit;">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="field">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Field Name</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.name}}</mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="filter">
                <mat-header-cell style="margin-right: 20px;" *matHeaderCellDef>Filter</mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell style="margin-right: 20px;" *matCellDef="let element">
                    {{element.filter}}
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
                <mat-header-cell style="text-align: end;" *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="text-align: end;">
                    <mat-icon (click)="deleteReturn(element.id, 'standard')" style="font-size: 24px; cursor: pointer;" matTooltip="Delete">clear</mat-icon>
                </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="reportFieldsColumns"></mat-header-row>
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: reportFieldsColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table doesn't detect dynamic changes at runtime, you have to refresh the table yourself.

Have a look at [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axjzov). You can see that after pushing a new element to the array, I have to reset the dataSource manually.

Comment: Link only answer. Pls put the relevant code in the answer itself so that when the link goes dead in the future the answer is still of use.